# Can an embedded flash component be linked to another page using HTML?

Tags: html

I am making a page using only HTML and a bit of flash, I know that I can link the object directly using flash but I want to link it to another page using HTML so that when someone click on it, it opens a different page. Can it be done using only HTML? If so, how?

Comment: Put an absolutely positioned div over it which is wrapped in a tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so, if you have a flash component named movie.swf, using this code:

```
<div onmousedown="window.location.href='http://www.yoursite.com'" height=100 width=100>
<object>
    <param name="movie" value="movie.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="movie.swf" height=100 width=100></embed>
</object>
```